# Drupal display 3rd party content with script

Tags: javascript, drupal

I am trying to add this script tag, which will display some 3rd party content, to my drupal page within admin -> content -< edit (using Drupal 7.36):

```
<script src="http://www.applitrack.com/dex/onlineapp/defaultlinks.asp?vacancyURL=http://www.applitrack.com/dex/onlineapp/jobpostings/view.asp"></script>
```

However, when I save and reload, the page completely ignores the script I added and shows a blank content area. I have the text format set to 'PHP Code', and there appear to be no restrictions on the html tags allowed. I have tried each of the different text formats, but to no avail. Any suggestions as to what else I may need to do would be greatly appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to add js to drupal is with the drupal core funciton [drupal_add_js](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7).

```
drupal_add_js('http://example.com/example.js', 'external');
```

Create a very basic module and include something similar to that line in the hook_init function (if it's included on every page). If it is specific to a form include it in a form alter instead. Lot of other options to make it specific to the page its needed on but the general rule is include it only where it is needed.

Comment: You can do this in your template.php file, preprocess_page or preprocess_html (not sure), you don't even need a module for this.

Comment: @Flo I do not recommend doing this in the template.php file. It is against Drupal best practices to use non theme specific code in template.php file. It is bad for performance and tends to make the code difficult to manage as the one file gets bloated. Also it will only include the code for one theme. If you ever change themes your code gets lost. I usually create a module called mycompany_general as a sort of catch all for code like this.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to change the ckeditor settings to make sure script tags are allowed
admin/config/content/ckeditor

This way however is not best practice and I suggest against it. 
Edit your html.tpl.php template and add that js call near the bottom of your code.

Comment: This is a good option if you need the script included on every page for that theme. If you want it to span multiple themes or don't want it on every page for that theme the code should go into a module.